# What is the function of this "to" here?

Tags: infinitives, syntactic-analysis, particles

> Old people did not know enough once, perchance, to fetch fresh fuel to keep the fire a-going; new people put a little dry wood under a pot, and are whirled round the globe with the speed of birds, in a way **to** kill old people, as the phrase is.

I think this is "in a way that kills old people."

But I've only encountered this version: "the way to do something...".

Am I right? Is this usage not common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be [a quote from *Walden*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=t181mPLCad4C&pg=PT11&lpg=PT11&dq=Old+people+did+not+know+enough+once,+perchance,+to+fetch+fresh+fuel+to+keep+the+fire+a-going&source=bl&ots=uwnDQEbKu3&sig=6ZJF0Ckt4olBbBUEfFBrbT41Il4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PImdUpWWMqqr7AaXx4GIAQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Old%20people%20did%20not%20know%20enough%20once%2C%20perchance%2C%20to%20fetch%20fresh%20fuel%20to%20keep%20the%20fire%20a-going&f=false) by Henry David Thoreau (1817–1862). The English is archaic, evidenced not only by the infinitive verb you query, but also *perchance* and *a-going*.

He does indeed mean “whirled around the globe at the speed of birds, in such a way as would kill old people” (that is, people of a former age). The quote is describing how people have changed from former times to the present; how knowledge has increased, and technology; and how ancient peoples could not survive in the present.

Your assessment “the way to do something” is correct, except here it’s simply **a** way — one among many — to achieve a result.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comment. So this usage to infinitive verb is not common in modern English. As you suggested, "in such a way as would.." is more common?

Comment: *Such a way* would be more common now, I think. The use of the infinitive is not uncommon, as the version you have encountered demonstrates.

Comment: So I could say, "I said "Thank you" in a way to suggest a soupçon of sarcasm" to mean "I said "Thank you " in a way that suggested a soupcon of sarcasm"?

Comment: You could indeed! That puts your first comment in a whole new light :-)

Comment: No no...That was just an example..No relation with my first comment. Im sorry.

Comment: No worries :-))

Comment: Come to think of it, what is the subject of "are whirled around"? and this usage of "whirl around" is not comprehensible...

Comment: The *around* goes with *around the globe;* that particular phrase is in the passive voice and doesn't have a true subject.

Comment: but "what" is "whirled"? usually whirl doesn't come with an object.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/whirl

Comment: Thank you. But I don't see the logic here. Young people now can keep a fire going and they go around the world rapidly? "fire" and "these young people going global" are very unrelated to me. What am I missing here?

Comment: Not *young* people. *Modern* people: the people of this present age. Ancient people couldn't keep a fire going; modern people have boilers and can control fire at will. Ancient people couldn't travel fast; modern people can be whirled round the globe on railways or in aircraft; ancient people wouldn't be able to cope with modern ways.

Comment: Oh so, here it states two things about development. "Keeping fire going" and "modern transport"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this means "to kill, in a way, the old (i.e. previous) people". In other words, not to literally kill, but figuratively kill. Maybe culturally or in some way like that.

I believe the writer deliberately avoided the second comma after "in a way" because that would suggest the wrong meaning "whirled with the speed of birds, in a way, to kill" (whirled in a way, in order to kill rather than whirl in order to kill, in a way).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but what I wanted to know was the function of this "to".